# Quicksort no se implementa bien

Tags: array, c, quicksort

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que tengo que ordenar un array de doubles mediante quicksort, pero cuando lo implemento, el programa se termina sin error ninguno. ¿Qué puede ser? Hay unos 100 elementos en el array, y lo he rellenado en la misma función utilizando un for. El array se rellena a la perfección, el error viene cuando pasa por la llamada a QuickSort.

Un saludo y gracias, adjunto el código

```
tAlumnos *aux = alumnado;
int cont_alumnos = contador_alumnos;
double arr_alumnos[contador_alumnos];
for (int i = 0; i < contador_alumnos; i++)
{
    arr_alumnos[i] = notaMedia(aux);
    aux++;
}
for(int i = 0; i < contador_alumnos; i++){
    printf("Nota %d: %lf\n", i, arr_alumnos[i]); // Aquí se ve que el array está relleno
}
quickSort(arr_alumnos, 0, contador_alumnos); // El error viene aquí
        
printf("============================================\n");

for (int i = 0; i < contador_alumnos; i++)
{
    printf("Nota %d: %lf\n", i, arr_alumnos[i]);
}
printf("============================================\n");
menu();
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe ¿Cuál es el código de quickSort? Si el error está allí eso es lo que deberíamos revisar. Además, deberías explicar cuál es el error. Puedes editar tu pregunta para agregar esa información.

Comment: @SJuan76 El Quicksort funciona perfectamente, porque lo he probado aislado en otro proyecto y ordena genial todos los elementos. El problema surge cuando le cargo más números

Comment: "El problema surge cuando le cargo más números." Eso no es lo mismo que *perfectamente*.

Comment: La llamada debería ser `quickSort(arr_alumnos, 0, contador_alumnos - 1);`, sino estás accediendo a un elemento más allá del final de vector.

Comment: @EequiisVásquez Sigue sin funcionar!!

Comment: @SJuan76 Es que el algoritmo funciona bien, pero no se si es por algo de memoria o algún tema distinto

Comment: Para empezar, ese código no debería compilar, salvo que `contador_alumnos` sea una constante. No puedes crear un array de tamaño fijo usando como tamaño una expresión variable porque se crea en tiempo de compilación y ahí no tienes valor para la variable. Esto no debería compilar: `double arr_alumnos[contador_alumnos];`. Me parece que el problema lo tienes en la definición de array que luego le estás pasando al algoritmo

Comment: @HugoHernandez ¿Qué es tAlumnos un struct? Si es así añade ese código para que así sea más fácil ayudarte, si puedes todo el programa. Otra parte contador_alumnos no puede ser una variable global porque si es así te saltaria un error de ejecucion debido a que estarías cambiando el valor cada cierto tiempo.

Comment: @SuperG280 algunos compiladores siguen aceptando los VLA y los tratan a su manera. No es estándar pero puede compilar con algunos compiladores

Comment: @HugoHernandez tu dices que el algoritmo funciona ... pero a la vez dices que falla. Si preguntas aquí es porque no consigues dar con la respuesta. ¿No crees que es preferible darnos lo que te pedimos y tener así más opciones de obtener respuestas?

Comment: @HugoHernandez dices que _el programa se termina sin error ninguno_. ¿A qué te refieres? **¿Cuál es el error?** ¿La ejecución es abortada por el sistema? ¿Termina bien pero los elementos no están bien ordenados? Por favor, explica detalladamente qué error es el que estás teniendo.

Comment: @eferion Los VLA si es estándar, se introdujo en C99.

Comment: @HugoHernandez Te invito a [Como preguntar.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MrDave1999 desde C11 ya no forma parte del estándar. Bueno, más bien ha pasado a ser una característica opcional, no es código portable